# MySQL: How to get n latest rows of a distinct type

Tags: sql, mysql

Putting this as simply as I can, I have the following table structure:

`Date | Type | Title`

Say `Type` is a value in the range 1-10, I have 1,000s of records in the table, and I want the 5 most recent records of unique type. So the result would be something like:

```
             Date | Type | Title
2009-06-04 14:32:00 | 4 | Zeppo
2009-06-04 14:31:00 | 2 | Groucho
2009-06-04 14:30:00 | 8 | Harpo
2009-06-04 14:29:00 | 5 | Gummo
2009-06-04 14:28:00 | 3 | Chico
```

Seems like I either want `DISTINCT` to only apply to the `Type` column, or I want a `GROUP BY` which will apply *after* an `ORDER BY` clause.

All in MySQL 4.

Comment: Is Gummo supposed to have `2` for it's type?

Answer (score 7):

Am I missing something?  The easy solution seems to be:

```
SELECT  MAX(date) AS max_date, type, title
FROM    table
GROUP BY
        type  
ORDER BY
        max_date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

And it should be extremely fast.

Comment: @Adam: I think your solution it what author really _means_, but it does not return "5 most recent records of each type" as he _says_.

Comment: @Adam: but I think it's a +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't test in for `MySQL 4`, but in `MySQL 5` this can be easily done.

You'll need to have some kind of a `PRIMARY KEY` in your table for this to work.

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  type,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    mytable li
                WHERE   li.type= dlo.type
                ORDER BY
                        li.type DESC, li.date DESC, li.id DESC
                LIMIT 4, 1
                ), CAST(0xFFFFFFFF AS DECIMAL)) AS mid
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  date
                FROM    mytable li
                WHERE   li.type= dlo.type
                ORDER BY
                        li.type DESC, li.date DESC, li.id DESC
                LIMIT 4, 1
                ), '9999-31-12') AS mdate
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT type
                FROM    t_mytable dl
                ) dlo
        ) lo, t_mytable l
WHERE   l.type >= lo.type
        AND l.type  <= lo.type
        AND (l.date, l.id) >= (lo.mdate, lo.mid)
```

See this entry in my blog for more detail on how it works:

- [**Advanced row sampling**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/) - how to select `N` rows for a `GROUP` in `MySQL`.

If you cannot add a `PRIMARY KEY` to implement this solution, you may try using less efficient one using system variables:

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  @lim := 5,
                @cg := -1
        ) vars,
        mytable l
WHERE   CASE WHEN @cg <> type THEN @r := @lim ELSE 1 END > 0
        AND (@r := @r - 1) >= 0
        AND (@cg := type) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
        type DESC, date DESC
```

It's described here:

- [**Row sampling**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/05/row-sampling/)

**Update:**

If you don't want to select `5` records for each type (which would give `5 x number of types` records in the resultset), but instead want to select `5` latest records with distinct type (which would give `5` records in the resultset), use this query:

```
SELECT  date, type, title
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.date > m.date
                AND mi.type = m.type
        )
ORDER BY
        date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

If you have lots of types, this will be more efficient that using `GROUP BY`, provided you have an index on `date`.

Comment: Great articles.  I do think you can just tell MySQL which index to use however instead of your trick at the bottom of Advanced Row Sampling:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: @Adam: the index will be used, but only for coarse filtering on the first column along with USING WHERE on the second one. Trust me, every row of that query is on purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming query performance is somewhat important and you're stuck with MySQL 4 I would go with something like so:

```
SELECT Date, Type, Title
FROM (
    SELECT Date, Type, Title
    FROM Table
    WHERE Type = 1
    ORDER BY Date
    LIMIT 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Date, Type, Title
    FROM Table
    WHERE Type = 2
    ORDER BY Date
    LIMIT 1

    ...
) x
ORDER BY Date
LIMIT 5
```

It's not pretty, but it should get the job done and quickly. If you're regularly adding new values to the types column, this may not be for you as it would require modifying the query regularly.

I think derived tables were added in 4.1, so you'll need to be at least that high in the 4 series. If you were on version 5 or a different database, there would be nicer ways to approach this.

Comment: It IS 4.1, so I might look into derived tables.
Unfortunately, the type value will be changing frequently enough to make this approach a bit of a pain maintenance-wise, but it's an interesting approach - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a good case for the union statement and nested selects.

Something along the lines of:

```
select t.date, t.type, t.title from (Select top 5 table.Date, table.Type, table.Title from table where type = 1 order by table.date desc) as t

union

select t2.date, t2.type, t2.title from (Select top 5 table.Date, table.Type, table.Title from table where type = 2 order by table.date desc) as t2

[...]

select t10.date, t10.type, t10.title from (Select top 5 table.Date, table.Type, table.Title from table where type = 10 order by table.date desc) as t10

order by type, date
```

Unfortunately, I only have sql server 2008 to test this on here, so ymmv; but this is pretty basic stuff and it ought to work as both nested selects and unions are supported in mysql 4.0 according to the reference guide. (I've added the as clause to the nested from statement based on the mysql documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select
    T.*
from
        (select
            max(date) dt,
            Type
        from
            table
        group by type
        order by dt desc
        limit 5) subQuery 
        inner join table T on T.date = subQuery.dt and T.Type = subQuery.Type
```

I've only tried it on MySQL 5. This is assuming the date field is unique. If you have a primary key other than date, then use that in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a little late, but had the same problem and figured out how: so I'm Posting.

```
SELECT t.Date, t.Type, t.Title
FROM (SELECT Date, Type, Title FROM table ORDER BY Date DESC) AS t
GROUP BY t.Type LIMIT 5;
```

I don't think there's a simpler solution.

***Explanation***

1. The inner SELECT gets executed first. This returns a table with
   rows, DESC sorted on Date column. In this table, the latest entry for
   a particular type is above all the other entries of the same type.
   This return table is renamed t.
2. Now a GROUP BY operation is performed on this table based on the Type column.
   The result would be the first row encountered, of each type.
3. Now add a LIMIT condition to
   get the first 5 rows.